# Present description tooltip when hovering the pointer on files

Tags: nautilus

I wish to see a description of a file when mouse hovers over that file much like you get "program name" when you hover over an icon in launcher. How can I do it?

In my view there must be some CSS file to make this change and include the description. How to find the location of the CSS file?

Example: When I hover over a file, named some "project.css", suppose I set the required text to be displayed as "main css file of the project", this text must be displayed if I hover over the file.

I know this sounds over ambitious, but having such feature would be so awesome mainly if you don't name your files correctly.

Comment: Description like "text file" or description like the first lines of text?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Just wanted to help you with the question accuracy.  I actually have no idea what to say for an answer haha.